# observable - how do I return values using forEach and setTimeout? (nothing to do with Rxjs)

Tags: javascript, observablehq

I'm new to observablehq notebook.
I found this is very helpful tool for me to prototype my visuals.

My question is
How do I iterate an array and return values with setTimeout of javascript?

My approach is as below.

1. array is declared

   `arr = [1,2,3,4,5]`
2. iterate the array and return values

   ```
      arr.forEach((d,i)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      return d
    },i*1000)})
   ```

How do I achieve this?

I saw similar posting using Rxjs but I don't use that.
Is there a basic / elementary way of achieving this?

I think the reason that this isn't working is something to do with closure.
But can't think of solving the issue.

Comment: Nothing to do with closures. Anything returned from a `setTimeout()` callback is lost.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

you have to wait of course, it would take a while

```
{
  //Now, iterate over the array with setTimeout
  let myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  let newMap = [];

  for (let [index, d] of myArr.entries()) {
    const abc = await new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(d);
      }, 1000 * index);
    });
    newMap.push(abc);
  }

  return newMap;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can try the solution below

```
    myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

//Now, iterate over the array with setTimeout
myArr.forEach(function(d, i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(d);
        return d;
    }, 1000 * i);
});
```

Comment: it says 'undefined'

Comment: What's undefined exactly?

Comment: I was expecting it would return values in my observable notebook but it returns nothing and doesn't render any value in my observable notebook. it would work perfectly fine with javascript but not for observable notebook environment.